# MongoDb User with readWrite can create database

Tags: mongodb, security, role

I dont understand why my user can create data base. 
The user "toto" with role "readwrite" on DB1 can create a DataBase (db2). And with the same account "toto" I can create a user and affect this user to db2.

it mean, "Toto" can access at this database.

There is no security, have you got a idea what is wrong ?
thanks
Thomas

Comment: Welcome to DBA StackExchange! With current info it is hard to guess what may have gone wrong. Can you please edit your question to include more details: MongoDB server version, type of deployment (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster), and steps to reproduce your issue (for example, using the `mongo` shell).

Comment: If you are able to authenticate successfully as user `toto`, one possibility is that you have created users but haven't [restarted your MongoDB instance with access control enabled](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control). You could confirm this by connecting without providing any credentials and trying to run `show dbs`. If access control is enabled, the expected result is an error message like `not authorized on admin to execute command`.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks for your answer, With many research, I've found solution, see bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'va found a solution. It was dificult to find the information.

By default your mongoDB doesnt need authentification. So if you create user, you can log in with it, but you have "root" access.

To enable authentification, ans enable roles, you need to modify your mongo.cfg (config file) and add this :

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Dont forget to restart the server.
Thanks you for your answer.

Thomas